# Spark Local vs Cluster

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

What is the Spark cluster equivalent of standalone's local[N]. I mean, the value we set as a parameter of local as N, which parameter takes it in the cluster mode?

Answer (score 0):

In `local[N]` - `N` is the maximum number of cores can be used in a node at any point of time.

In cluster mode you can set `--executor-cores N`.
It means that each executor can run a maximum of `N` tasks at the same time in an executor.

Answer (score 0):

In **cluster** mode, one executor will run on one worker node, which means that one executor will takes all the cores on the worker node. It could result in under-utilization of the resources. Keep in mind, **driver** will also takes one worker node.