# Spark local cluster vs threading

Tags: pyspark

As mentioned into below link Spark Local vs Cluster

[Spark Local vs Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293448/spark-local-vs-cluster)

It means, spark local run on local machine with number of threads,

Can I assume it is similar to create a thread from threading module. and we do not need to bother any other thing,

Can I explore this way,

1. convert large list into dataframe
2. use udf function and apply manipulation on frame
3. convert dataframe to list.

will it better approach or efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "Bother any other thing"?  And also "better approach or efficient" compared with what approach?

Comment: I mean, locking, synronize and race condition of thread, if I convert data such as way and use dataframe and apply udf, then it will be multithreaded application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully understand your question.

> It means, spark local run on local machine with number of threads,

Yes, both local mode and cluster mode, you can set the configs to let multiple threads run on each node. Each executor would be one thread.

> Can I assume it is similar to create a thread from threading module. and we do not need to bother any other thing,

I think so. I believe they are just different threads each performing a different executor's job as if they are different machines.

> Can I explore this way,

I do not understand which method you compare to. Sorry.

Comment: my intension was, I am trying to code as multithread application  into local machine later realize if I organize data into dataframe and use pyspark udf, it will be multithread application, so no need to worry about lock, synchronize or other  thread parameter

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you can understand it in this way. Spark is designed for distributed computing, even though there are local threads in use, all the thread usage is still under distributed computing framework.   And as the spark treat each executor as an individual image. so even if multiple threads are used, each thread just handles individual executors. Each executor has its own memory space. They do not share memory.  That's different from general thread-based computing.  So my understanding was yes, you don't need to worry about the lock, synchronize or other thread pararmeters.